# How to create custom safe list in jsoup to allow RFC 822 / RFC 2047 encoded address

Tags: java, jsoup

Consider the string `Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>` is safe, now if I perform Jsoup clean operation like below:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.clean("Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>", Safelist.none()));
```

It will only return `Amogh` (considering email address as unsafe) how can we make it to return `Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>` after cleaning any other HTML code.

Safe case:

`System.out.println(Jsoup.clean("Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>", Safelist.none())); // Should print Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>`

Unsafe case:

`System.out.println(Jsoup.clean("Amogh <rover886@gmail.com><script>alert()</script>", Safelist.none())); // Should print Amogh <rover886@gmail.com>`

Comment: I would not use a safelist for this since email verification is already a well defined task. I would use a regex to pick out the email first then run safelist on the rest. Something along the lines of `^(?:<name>.+)\s+<(?:<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)>` (this approximates the email regex. https://emailregex.com/ for the full one) then run `Safelist.simpleText()` on the resulting name group.

Comment: Maybe instead of *fixing* problem there is a chance to *prevent* it? Maybe instead of having `<address@server>` there is a chance to have its encoded version like `&gt;address@server&lt;` which will be left after jsoup will cleanup `<script>` element. Then you can decode what is left.

Comment: @Locke, Oh! okay, thanks for the suggestion. With that said, what I go with regex as `^[a-zA-Z]+\s+<[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?>$` which will strictly check the string for desired format. So, If match is found then good to go.